# Open sofrce createRecord in aura in popup modal instead of subtab in console

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, lightning-web-components, create-records

I am trying to open "Standard Task" create page in console but its opening as a subtab. I need to open it as a modal popup on same lightning recordpage. Please help.

```
 var createRecordEvent = $A.get('e.force:createRecord');
        if ( createRecordEvent ) {
            //map the new fields here
            createRecordEvent.setParams({
                'entityApiName': 'Task',
                'defaultFieldValues': {
                    'WhoId' : component.get("v.recordId")
                }
            });
            createRecordEvent.fire();
        }
```

Comment: tried your code and it works just right - opens as modal dialog.

Comment: Look to see how your Console application is configured for opening related records. Console operates entirely different than the regular UI. Also, I see you've tagged this for LWC. At this time, the Lightning Console does not fully support LWC. It's an issue with the Console, not LWC. You'll want to use Aura Wrappers until they're fully supported.

Comment: @pnoytechie - It opens as modal popup in Lightning sales app but as a primary tab in lightning sales console but I want to open this as a modal popup in lightning console.

Comment: @crmprogdev my requirement is to show new task standard layout as modal popup in lightning console from custom quick action button at top. I am using above code but it opens as a subtab. I dont have issues using aura or LWC if I can accomplish this.

Comment: i think that's the behavior in console. even the OOB New Task/Event buttons/menu items in "Open Activities" related list do the same.

Comment: I'd expect you'll need to invoke the Lightning Console JS API to break out of the Console's standard behavior that's been defined for Tasks.